# Render html doc using iframe and update couple fields in the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I have this in my html doc that I get from API.

`<p>name: <span id="name"></span></p>`

And when I render this in react in `.js` component with `iframe srcDoc`, I want `id="name"` to be dynamic, so I can change it with passing any props, for ex if I pass 'Nature', then it should display like this on UI `name: Nature`.

Can someone please help with this or any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
function DynamicIframe({ content, dynamicValue }) {
  const dynamicContent = content.replace(
    '<span id="name"></span>',
    `<span id="name">${dynamicValue}</span>`
  );

  return <iframe srcDoc={dynamicContent} ></iframe>;
}
```

And for security issues you can use `Sanitization`.

Comment: Up vote the answer so the others could find the answer. I will put an update for the input once I have some time